# TypeError: Cannot read property 'player' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently working on a project using Angular. Since I am pretty new to programming, I don't know what to do with this Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'player' of undefined.
```

Basically I  don't know where and how to define this property.
Here is the Code I am using: 
My game.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="playerBox">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="player">Player: </td>
      <td class="player" [innerText]="games.player"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="player">Round: </td>
      <td class="player" [innerText]="games.round"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
  <p [innerText]="games.question"></p>
  <button class="button" (click)="nextQuestion()">Next</button>
  <button class="button" routerLink="/home">Home</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Game.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionService } from '../../services/question.service';
import { Game } from "../../models/game";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.sass']
})
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {

  games: Game;

  constructor(private questionService: QuestionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nextQuestion();
  }

  nextQuestion() {
    this.questionService.getQuestion().subscribe(data => {
      this.games = data;
    });
  }

}
```

Question.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { O`enter code here`bservable } from 'rxjs';
import { Game } from '../models/game';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  /* Get question from DB */
  getQuestion(): Observable<Game> {
    return this.http.get<Game>("//localhost:8443/api/next");
  }

  resetAll() {
    return this.http.get("//localhost:8443/api/reset");
  }

}
```

And finally Game.ts:

```
export class Game {
  player: string;
  round: number;
  question: string;
}
```

The error is thrown in game.component.html line 6. 
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is your API returning data? Check if it is throwing an error..

Comment: The Angular/Typescript looks good. I would start by seeing what your API returns. What is returned when you navigate to this in the browser? //localhost:8443/api/next

Comment: If api is working, trying adding games?.player and games?.round

Comment: Yes the API works perfectly fine. I just had to adjust the code as the first reply said. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http get request is asynchronous call so in that case the `games` will be an undefined until it get the value try to set initial value for the `games` property

```
 games: Game = new Game();
```

another way is use `?.` (safe navigation operator)

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="player">Player: </td>
      <td class="player" [innerText]="games?.player"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="player">Round: </td>
      <td class="player" [innerText]="games?.round"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```typescript
nextQuestion() {
    this.questionService.getQuestion().subscribe(data => {
         // Put debugger to check the value for games.
         debugger
         this.games = data;
    });
  }
```

First check is the data came back from the server to your **getQuestion** is correct, and expected it is not coming at all, then with debugger check, you can see the values assigned to games for more investigation, otherwise set default value for game, it will be changed when the data coming in the subscriber.

If games is assigned correctly but the player is optional then use it like this in your HTML

```html
[innerText]="games?.player"
```